# How can I maintain integrity when requested to use gender pronouns yet still be loving?

Tags: ethics, identity

I have friends who request certain gender pronouns are used, which I do not believe to be correct. I have thought about this topic at some length and concluded that while using these pronouns would be loving to my friends, it clashes with my conscience. The crux is that ethically/morally I do not believe that a person's self-perception and wishes to be recognised a certain way should take priority when we disagree.

This could be abstracted to any situation where we disagree of course not just gender identity, but given this is typically closely linked with a person's very sense of self I can't see a way to put my position that wouldn't be taken as an attack on the person themself.

If I cannot in good conscience refer to someone by their preferred pronoun for equally deep-seated reasons, how can I proceed? We would surely struggle for it not to be an issue because while most people are gracious to accidentally mis-gendering if I am corrected and simply ignore it, that's going to be quite obvious eventually.

---

*Hopefully an obvious addendum but I realise this is very much an emotive, non-academic issue to many people. I do not wish to get into the details _of_ the issue. I could rewrite this as generically "when we disagree over an issue both of us feel is not negotiable" if that is more helpful.*

Comment: Waiting for it to become obvious is itself rather deceptive. If this is how you feel you should let your interlocutors know upfront, and explain your ethical reasons. Then both of you will have a decision to make: either one of you gives, or you stop interacting and go separate ways.

Comment: @Dcleve that is not your position to judge, nor is it my position to convince you. If you're saying philosophers cannot discuss a theoretical situation then I would very much reject _that_. You are taking as axiomatic that I am _being_ rude and callous and making huge assumptions what can/cannot be a valid argument.

Comment: @another_name I'd prefer my question doesn't head in this sort of direction

Comment: I don't know what would be best to do in this situation but I would refuse to play the gender-pronoun game. The whole thing is profoundly daft. But you don't mention which pronouns you don't want to use so I'm only guessing the exact problem. .

Comment: Typical protocol is to avoid contentious issues like politics, religion, etc. in most social scenarios, unless they're somehow on-topic.  Gender pronouns can be tricky because they're widely used in polite contexts, before the relatively recent stuff.  The solution would seem to be to shift them back out like everything else -- which, in this case, would seem to be using gender-neutral language.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think we do have to consider the elephant in the room, here: do you want to *keep* these people as friends, are are you willing to sacrifice their friendship for the sake of your principles? Because that seems to be the dilemma you are facing. People who have reached the point where they want to be addressed with alternate pronouns are going to be offended if you steadfastly refuse to do so, and it places you in the unfortunate position of the bully who insists on referring to people by names they dislike.

Imagine if I insisted on calling someone 'dweeb,' despite their frequent, angry objections; imagine I justified it by stating that I honestly believe that person *is* a dweeb, and see no reason to use any other (overtly false) description. Is my principle of honesty sufficient to override their dislike of the label, and is it reasonable to insist that they put up with my behavior?

You do not have to agree about their perceived gender identity; that is a matter for you and your conscience. You have a right to dispute and debate matters of practical concern, within reason. But using this pronoun or that is a matter of no practical consequence, and accommodating people on that kind of thing is a litmus of social respect. And nothing will kill a friendship faster than overt displays of disrespect.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I'm not sure I totally agree with the argument I _must_ act as they request to be friends, as a parallel example I know people who are opposed to gay marriage who have gay (married) friends. I would debate "using this pronoun or that is a matter of no practical consequence" too. My concern is that _by_ doing so, I am implicitly validating that position and feel I'm lying to myself (I have tried this approach out of love for my friend but it prickles my conscience). Further if my friend knows I am speaking contrary to what I believe, wouldn't _they_ rightly be upset?

Comment: @Mr.Boy — This is the eternal problem of perspective. You complain about being *forced* to abide by your friend's preferred form of address; Your friend (I'm sure) will complain about being *forced* to abide by your standards. It's become a competitive mode where the only options left are surrender or fighting. Do the people you mentioned with married gay friends refuse to acknowledge that these friends are legally married? That would make for some fun dinner parties...

Comment: this is sound advice, but it's probably not philosophy.

Comment: @Mr.Boy — 'Validation' is a tricky thing. You may not want to validate an act, or intention, or idea; I can understand that. But if you don't validate the *person* involved, then you are guilty of objectification. Maybe if you sit down with your friend and have a long talk about why you refuse to use the preferred pronouns you can come to some compromise that your conscience will bear. But you'll *both* have to give some ground.

Comment: @another_name — The fact I'm not spelling things out in philosophical jargon doesn't imply that I'm not working from a philosophy. But you're right: this whole question is probably a poor fit for this site. A bit too 'Ask Amy'... It would seem ***odd*** to suddenly burst out with (say) a Heideggerian take on gender identity.

Comment: but also apt @TedWrigley

Comment: @Mr.Boy You say it prickles your conscience but today this is largely fashion. You know to get attention and to have some forbidden fun. We need to do what they did in the old days, and even today, and confine this to Mardi Gras and the weekend before. Yes there are some people where there is the true mental and physical need to be the other sex. But for the majority it’s just fashion and the Catholics had the right idea with Mardi Gras. Do whatever you want, and then stop and suffer over it for 40 days, then endure the drudgery until the next year.

Comment: @TedWrigley I'm not forcing them or even encouraging them to change how they act  so I don't think that's entirely accurate. But the wider point of colliding worldviews is entirely valid. There may be NO answer

Comment: @Mr.Boy — Aren't you though? Just because your position is passive doesn't make it any less aggressive. If I stand in the middle of a hallway, arms akimbo, and refuse to move, I am *forcing* people to walk around me or turn back, even though I am not doing anything active. You are clinging to a principle and *de facto* (pardon the ironic phrasing) c**k-blocking something important to these people. But you're right, there's probably no immediate answer. The extremes are always an irresistible force pressing against an immovable object, while the center inches its way along...

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining integrity would mean you want to be honest whilst having strong moral principles.
Integrity is a question of not having two faces - if you really believe something, why would you “say one thing here and another thing there”.

This in itself is almost an impossible task to do as humans, since we so frequently make mistakes which undermine our “strong moral principles”.
It can work, however, if you attribute these principles to a perfect, external source - where the idea of integrity would shift from upholding one’s own principles to ‘maintaining a loyalty’ to its perfect source (or evidencing your belief by following given principles).

It is very good, we should all think, that you have involved the question of love - because, by most moral standards, love has been what sands down the rough edges of any crude attempts at following our moral principles.

If you would like to be loving, yet maintain this integrity (or evidenced loyalty to, what you believe to be, perfection) - could I suggest humility to be a key propagator for the two.

If you truly believe something, discussing the topic with your friend in true humility may be the best step.
Being proactive, perhaps, in setting up a good environment to talk about it - I.e. inviting them to a coffee shop, confessing that you have been restless about this certain topic and would really appreciate if you could just have a half hour to talk about it.

This discussion may make you even better friends; paying for their drink, or other way of making them feel comfortable, will show you care about how they feel; allowing them to be part of your decision-making (rather than coming to a conclusion without conferring) will show you care about what they think; and, finally, a humble stance will show you are truly struggling with this and want there to be peace.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the possibilities here:

1. **You're just resistant to change**. I have a close friend who changed his name. I didn't like his new name, I had trouble pronouncing it, I constantly forgot it, I felt it was unfair to people who knew him to have to learn a new name. Eventually I adjusted, and 20 years later, we're still friends. I can no longer imagine him by any name except his chosen one.  I think we can all agree in this scenario, you just have to adjust, and not be selfish.
2. **You feel threatened by this change.** I think this is another one where you have to get over it. It's not your life, it's not your body, it's not your pronouns. Nothing about *you* is changing, including your beliefs and commitments. If your personal gender identity is fragile, that's not your friend's problem.
3. **You have a genuine belief that anything that promotes, or fails to oppose "gender confusion" is significantly harmful to society.** If you feel this way, then you might have to accept that your friendship with this person is over. You have incompatible moral commitments. Be honest and up front about this, and part as amicably as possible.
4. **You feel this is personally harmful to your friend, and you don't want to be a part of that.** This is the most legitimate scenario. However, it's also a bit patronizing. You aren't this person's parent, guardian or priest. I think in this case, you owe them *one* solid direct conversation, where you make it clear how you feel. Share your concerns for them, and then shut up about it. In this last scenario, I still think you should use the pronouns they request. It's not like giving alcohol to an alcoholic or drugs to a drug addict. Using OR refusing those pronouns isn't going to change how they identify, it's only going to change how they feel about you and your relationship. **It's really just a baseline courtesy**. If you can't do that much, even if it feels icky, then this is another scenario where you accept the friendship is over.

Answer (score 1):

Let's generalise the problem. It boils down to the following: your friend would like you to behave in a way that conflicts with your personal values. You have a number of choices about how to respond. There is no absolutely right or wrong response, so it is up to you to decide. You can either make a choice based on your instinct, or you can try to make a more reasoned choice. If you want to do the former, just go with your gut feel. If you want to do the latter, one way to approach the decision is to list your options, identify their pros and cons, then weight the pros and cons according to your thoughts about their relative importance. For example, the possible options might include:

1. Go along with your friend's preferences and swallow your principles.
2. Ignore your friend's preferences and risk upsetting them.
3. Evade the problem by trying to avoid the need to use pronouns- instead, use the person's name.
4. Explain your dilemma to your friend, and ask if they mind if you don't use their preferred pronouns.
5. Agree to use their pronouns, but explain to them that you are doing so only out of respect for them and that you don't really agree with their request.
6. Try to become more tolerant by questioning your values.

The pros and cons of those options might include:

a) Maintaining your friendships
b) Not upsetting people
c) Having to make an effort to speak in a certain way
d) Not compromising your views

Possibly you could think of more pros and cons. Either way, you would need to rank the pros and cons in order of importance to you, and pick whichever option has pros that most outweigh the cons.

If my friends asked me to use particular pronouns, I would say sure, and try to remember to do so. If I forgot now and again, and my friends complained about it, I would say sorry but tell them to stop being so precious about it. That said, my views could be coloured by the fact that I was one of a very large number of children in my family, and our mum often got our names mixed up. That didn't bother us in the least, because we knew that our mum loved us. Hopefully your friends would feel that way if you forgot to use their preferred pronouns. If, on the other hand, they considered your ability to remember which pronouns to use to be more important than your friendship, then you might want to find better friends.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**: Do not overload pronoun-use with any kind of ontological claims. If you adopt the rule that you are using whatever pronoun for a person that that person prefers (guess as well as you can if they haven't told you), then your own understanding of how gender should work becomes mostly irrelevant for social interactions. Since now **by definition** "correct" and "preferred" pronoun coincide, there is no conflict anymore.

**Your question**: It seems to me that you are asking for a way to gain absolution for acting like an asshole, either by philosophical argument or by alternative kindness. This is fundamentally something many people try, but it never works. If you adopt a wordview that requires you to act like an asshole, you shouldn't expect this to be accepted as an excuse for the subsequent behaviour. What exactly the reasons behind problematic behaviour is usually matters little for the people suffering from it, and if possible, they will chose to disengage (or even retaliate).

Comment: I can see your point on the first part, effectively I internalise the decision to treat preferred gender pronouns as a 'social title'? On the second part I think you're either being rude, or simply unable to accept that someone who doesn't share your view on gender pronouns is anything other than an asshole... that discussion is exactly what I wish to avoid here.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone agrees there are gendered roles, even those that would claim these are social constructions that should be abolished, along with 'gender'.

I'm not sure what 'gender' means to your friends, but people kinda have the right to be addressed as they choose. If you continue to call someone "Nigel" on the grounds that it's their birth name, then I wouldn't worry about being their friend much.

We may be reluctant to suppose that someone is a woman when they are biologically male and not trans, especially if we are in relationship that is charged by more than gender. Be that sex, or not. But, if we suppose that gender is just an idealization of gender roles, and I can't think what else it is, arguing with them is just vacuous.

Comment: You've stated as a fact "people kinda have the right to be addressed as they choose". I think that's central to the debate not axiomatic... where is that right from and why should people have it? It certainly isn't a right we've historically held in the West.

Comment: why not? i may have a right to free speech, but you have a right to be addressed how you choose "[Each right trumps competing considerations in most circumstances, but there are certain circumstances in which another right with higher priority—or a pressing non-right consideration—determines what may or should be done.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rights/)" i can't see how the former right trumps the latter, as i see 'freedom of speech' as a weak hand. it seems obvious that's the case: even if i thought obama was ruining America, i have no right to use racist words, especially in public

Answer (score -2):

"The crux is that ethically/morally I do not believe that a person's self-perception and wishes to be recognised a certain way should take priority when we disagree"

In essence,  you think your opinion on this person's identity is more important than how they see themselves.

If the situation was reversed and your friend  decided that because of your mannerisms,  voice,  dress style and attitudes that you were much more appropriately addressed as being the opposite sex,  and they had "equally deep-seated reasons" for doing so, how much of a friend would you consider them?

Comment: I would say I fundamentally disagree an individual has the right to dictate how society  should recognise them rather than me personally. I think your comparison is a little flimsy because those are trivialities and the weight of history is on my side but ignoring that, _if_ they could explain their position coherently and demonstrate it was genuinely important to them and done for reasons of integrity not malice... I wouldn't rule out accepting that.

Comment: Your question wasn't about society.  It was about how you personally viewed your friend. You're shifting the argument to try and harness the wider world behind you.  Ditto with the "weight of history".  History has condoned all sorts of behaviour that we'd consider morally reprehensible today (slavery,  child labour etc etc). I don't think you should go looking to history to back you up. If you reframe the question as to whether society should accept an individual's self-identification, it would open the debate up. As it stands, it just makes you look like a poor friend IMHO.

Comment: @KevinRyan While I think your reversal argument is quite interesting, it ignores that one party desires to be seen as normal while the other wants to be recognized as so special and unique as to warrant a change to language.

Comment: @Uueerdo Your point hinges on the word "normal" and what you consider that to be. A lot of things we call normal today would have been aberrant 1000 years ago,  and vice versa.  Society evolves and changes, and language changes with it. At the moment,  at least in the West, we seem to be going through a period of reassessment of sexuality and identity. It's 'normal' that this will make a lot of people uncomfortable.

Comment: No, I am not using "normal" in the sense of what I consider to be normal, I am using "normal" in the most general sense, as in "conforming to the majority". There are many things that make me different from that, for good and ill, but I don't insist on those things being called out every time. It could be argued that "ugly" and "pretty" are both abnormal, and your comparison is based on equivocating one person not wanting to be called ugly (according to their standards) with another insisting on being called beautiful (according to their standards).

Comment: "Normal" is whatever we, as society, decide to call normal.   This changes over time. I can't explain it you better than that. The beautiful/ugly analogy doesn't hold up. We don't address people by their attractiveness,  but we do by their sexuality.  But it raises the question that maybe we shouldn't. Maybe society should do away with gender-oriented terms of address.

Comment: @KevinRyan eliminating gender-based pronouns altogether could help a lot (_"he"_ is technically semi-neutral already, and I think it still has too much baggage; but I think a new pronoun would just scream "special accommodation" to many people). I've thought of a similar solution to address the bathroom controversies as well; just make all bathrooms unisex.

Comment: @Uueerdo - yes, sure it will scream "special accommodation".  But then doesn't everything new at first ? I'm not any kind of LGBT activist, and new pronouns make me uneasy, but I see the way the world is changing.   The problem with unisex bathrooms is the urinals. Making all bathrooms into stalls is more expensive/less efficient.  Unless each sex becomes more comfortable with public urination (this is turning into a fucking weird conversation - I see why your name suits you ;-)   )

Comment: @KevinRyan haha, yeah, I would expect how public restrooms are built would change under such circumstances; urinals removed or turned into mini stalls, and normal stalls becoming a little less flimsy and with partitions extended vertically to nearer the ceiling and floor. ....and while it would be more expensive per stall, it would be one less room to maintain; so the costs might actually balance out.

Comment: I'm guessing your'e in the US. I'm based in Europe and cubicles in most countries tend to be built floor-to-near ceiling. I used to travel to the US a lot, and I was often struck by the minimal sheet between cubicles, even in expensive offices.  It used to remind me of drawings of Roman soldiers sitting side-by-side on the same plank with holes.